# Github action: Build and push docker image fails. server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

Tags: spring-boot, docker, github-actions, docker-push

I'm using the GitHub action "[Build and push Docker images](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images)" as it's from Docker and a top rated verified action.

The relevant snippet of my YAML file is as follows

```yaml
  - name: Set up QEMU
    uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
  - name: Set up Docker Buildx
    uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
  - name: Login to DockerHub
    uses: docker/login-action@v1
    with:
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
  - name: Build and push
    id: docker_build
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      push: true
      tags: user/app:latest
  - name: Image digest
    run: echo ${{ steps.docker_build.outputs.digest }}
```

[Just as it was shown in the example](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-and-push-docker-images#git-context). When the workflow runs, I consistently see the error

```
10 [stage-1 2/2] COPY --from=build /workspace/target/*.jar app.jar
#10 DONE 0.9s

#12 exporting to image
#12 exporting layers
#12 exporting layers 4.3s done
#12 exporting manifest sha256:dafb0869387b325491aed0cdc10c2d0206aca28006b300554f48e4c389fc3bf1 done
#12 exporting config sha256:f64316c3b529b43a6cfcc933656c77e556fea8e5600b6d0cce8dc09f775cf107 done
#12 pushing layers
#12 pushing layers 0.8s done
#12 ERROR: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
------
 > exporting to image:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed
Error: The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1
```

The contents of my Dockerfile for a standard spring-boot application is as shown below

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11-slim AS build
RUN mkdir -p /workspace
WORKDIR /workspace
COPY pom.xml /workspace
COPY src /workspace/src
RUN mvn -B -f pom.xml clean package -DskipTests

FROM openjdk:11-jdk-slim
COPY --from=build /workspace/target/*.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","app.jar"]
```

Any clue how this can be fixed?

I'm able to publish to docker-hub when using a different GitHub action as shown below

```
  - name: Build and push docker image
    uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@master
    with:
      name: bloque/sales-lead-management
      username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
      password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: Does the login used have push access to the "user/app" repo?

Comment: Yes it does. I used the other GitHub action and it works.

Comment: You used a different repo in the other GitHub action.

Comment: No, the same repository.

Comment: I just had this issue while pushing to the github container registry. in your case, check the log for the image tag, and make sure it match the docker hub username/repository format.

Comment: The answer from @OshanWisumperuma should be marked as the accepted answer.

Comment: For me the problem was that I had to login in Docker on the command line:

docker login --username=<username>

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a path context while using the Docker's `build-push-action`. It should look something like this:

```yaml
 - name: Build and push
   id: docker_build
   uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
   with:
     context: .
     file: Dockerfile
     push: true
     tags: user/app:latest
```

The `file` option is entirely optional, but if left out it will find the Dockerfile inside the root directory.

It's also recommended to use the [metadata action](https://github.com/docker/metadata-action) that provides more relevant metadata and tags for your Docker image.

Here is an example of how I did it for Spring Boot apps in few of my projects: https://github.com/moja-global/FLINT.Reporting/blob/d7504909f8f101054e503a2993f4f70ca92c2577/.github/workflows/docker.yml#L153